# How to Handle String Literals in Resource (.resx) Files

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, resx, string-literals

All, I have recently been learning a lot about localisation and the use of resource files (.resx). For a particular code, I have a .resx (and ascociated localised versions .de-DE.resx etc.) for each WinForm and two for the code (one for object strings [column names, etc.] and one for user messages [those displayed in message boxes etc.]). For the object strings I have no problem what-so-ever, but for the messages I have the following problem...

Take the message 'Search "SomeString" (23 hits in 3 files)', where  is a tab-space at the start of the message. To create such a message I use code like

```
String.Format("\tSearch \"{0}\" ({1} hits in {2} files)\n",
              strSearchString,
              nTotalHits,
              nNumberOfFiles);
```

The problem is now, when I include the string `"\tSearch \"{0}\" ({1} hits in {2} files)\n"` in the resource file I get the following output at runtime

```
\tSearch \"SomeString\" (23 hits in 3 files)\n
```

Clearly it is not treating the string literals as C# itself does. I know that to create the new line in the resource file I have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>, but what do you do for tabs et al.? Please don't say copy in to Word or Notepad++ and add the tab, copying back after or I will poke myself in the eye.

**What is the best way to convert the string literals contained in a resource file to *actual* string literal that are interpreted correctly by C#?**

Note that this sort of conversion is only going to happen with messages, so I am even willing to consider a runtime conversion.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you're going to be poking yourself in the eye, because that's *exactly* what you have to do. And I, too, am dismayed by this.

You could include the tab as a separate item, like this:

```
String.Format("{0}Search \"{1}\" ({2} hits in {3} files)\n",
          "\t",
          strSearchString,
          nTotalHits,
          nNumberOfFiles);
```

You can also type Alt-012 on the numeric keypad to enter a tab.

Finally, you could "escape" the tabs yourself by doing `string.Replace("\\t", "\t")` before passing the string to `string.Format()` and putting a "\t" into the string resource.

It's all a bit unsatisfactory tho! (And I'm sure you've already thought of all these ideas yourself...)

Comment: Daammmmn [Chris Tucker voice]! I have thought of doing the `String.Replace()` approach. But the fact that this is the state of affairs is _amazing_. I think for my messages I am going to `String.Replace()`. Again Matthew, thanks for your help.